# Search result that has a C and a number after the C in the Part Number Field in ColdFusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion, cfquery

I have a search results page that lists part numbers that engineers have to work on, but I only want part numbers displayed on the results page that have a C and then a number after the C in the part number. This is done in ColdFusion. How do I write this in the Where statement in my CFQuery? If I write Where Part_Number Like 'C%', it lists all the parts that have anything after a C in the part number like CBT-BGA. I want it to find only part numbers like this: C4560. I also tried this: Where Part_Number Like '^C[0-9]', but this doesn't show any results. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: `Like` does not support regex. Use something like `REGEXP` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to know which database you're using to give you a proper answer. The fact that you're using ColdFusion has no bearing on the structure of the SQL you need to generate.

If you're using SQL Server, [SQLShack says](https://www.sqlshack.com/t-sql-regex-commands-in-sql-server/) you should be able to use the `like` operator with some minimal pattern matching:

```
SELECT whatever FROM someTable WHERE someColumn LIKE '[C][0-9]%'
```

The syntax will likely be different for MySQL or Postgresql, but some quick searches should turn up the proper approach.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. We do have the Microsoft SQL Server.